# Do testCompile and androidTestCompile dependencies go into the built apk?

Tags: android, gradle

By default are `testCompile` and `androidTestCompile` dependencies along with any test cases written get packaged into the debug or release apk? If so, do we need to add some Proguard rules and or remove test cases before building release apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not. Or, more accurately, they are not included in any regular builds (e.g., `debug`, `release`). That is why the code is isolated in separate source sets and why the dependencies have the specific prefixes (`test`, `androidTest`).

Answer (score 1):

Instrumentation-tests dependencies specified using `androidTestCompile` (now `androidTestImplementation`) generally end up in a different, designated `.apk` (e.g. `app-debug-androidTest.apk`) - which gets installed on the device separately right before the tests are run, and they're not part of your app.

Unit-test dependencies specified by `testCompile` (now `testImplementation`) only get compiled into a temporary location, and thus do not get bundled into anything.

So in either case - no, these dependencies will not be part of the `.apk`.